# How to know the pixel size of a specific text on turtle graphics in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

As title, when I execute the following code

```
import turtle
turtle.write("some text")
```

I want to know the whole size (including height and width) of the string `some text` on the canvas of the turtle graphics.
How can I do that?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. `turtle` is a toy module and has very limited functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font size only tells you ***half*** of what you need to know, i.e. the height:

> The size of a font is typically taken to be the distance from the top
> of the highest character to the bottom of the lowest character.

From [FontSize.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize.html)

But we can get the width via setting the `move=` option of `turtle.write()` to `True`.  Here's a example where I want to draw a box around the text I've just drawn:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from tkinter.font import Font

TEXT = "Penny for your thoughts"  # arbitrary text
POSITION = (150, 150)  # arbitrary position

FONT_SIZE = 36  # arbitrary font size
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')  # arbitrary font

X, Y = 0, 1

def box(turtle, lower_left, upper_right):
    """ Draw a box but clean up after ourselves """

    position = turtle.position()
    isdown = turtle.isdown()

    if isdown:
        turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(lower_left)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(upper_right[X], lower_left[Y])
    turtle.goto(upper_right)
    turtle.goto(lower_left[X], upper_right[Y])
    turtle.goto(lower_left)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(position)

    if isdown:
        turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.goto(POSITION)

start = marker.position()
marker.write(TEXT, align='center', move=True, font=FONT)
end = marker.position()

font_config = Font(font=FONT)
font_ascent = font_config.metrics('ascent')
buffer = (font_config.metrics('linespace') - font_ascent) / 2

# Since it's centered, the end[X] - start[X] represents 1/2 the width
box(marker, (2 * start[X] - end[X], start[Y] - buffer), (end[X], start[Y] + font_ascent + buffer))

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Now, here's an example that draws the box first, fills it, and then draws the text into it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from tkinter.font import Font

TEXT = "Penny for your thoughts"  # arbitrary text
POSITION = (150, 150)  # arbitrary position

FONT_SIZE = 36  # arbitrary font size
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')  # arbitrary font

X, Y = 0, 1

# def box(turtle, lower_left, upper_right):
#     """ same as above example """
def box(turtle, lower_left, upper_right):
    """ Draw a box but clean up after ourselves """

    position = turtle.position()
    isdown = turtle.isdown()

    if isdown:
        turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(lower_left)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(upper_right[X], lower_left[Y])
    turtle.goto(upper_right)
    turtle.goto(lower_left[X], upper_right[Y])
    turtle.goto(lower_left)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(position)

    if isdown:
        turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()

font_config = Font(font=FONT)
font_ascent = font_config.metrics('ascent')
buffer = (font_config.metrics('linespace') - font_ascent) / 2
text_width = font_config.measure(TEXT)

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.fillcolor('pink')
marker.goto(POSITION)

# Since it's centered, we need to work with half widths
half_width = text_width / 2
marker.begin_fill()
box(marker, (POSITION[X] - half_width, POSITION[Y] - buffer), (POSITION[X] + half_width, POSITION[Y] + font_ascent + buffer))
marker.end_fill()

marker.write(TEXT, align='center', font=FONT)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, what you have done is my final goal. Thank you very much. I want to use turtle graphics to layout text such like latex.

Answer (score -1):

The default font for `turtle.write` is 'Arial' with a font-size of 8px as described in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write.

The height and width of the text is dependent on the `font` parameter.

Comment: So that I can have an estimation of width by `len(string)*8`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922295/calculating-the-pixel-size-of-a-string-with-python

Comment: I found a similar solution about tkinter, but no solution about turtle graphics...

Answer (score -1):

Though Brandon pretty much gave the answer, let me give you an example:

```
>>>>import turtle
>>>>turtle.write('hey hello this is DSP',font=('consolas',8,'bold'))
```

This would do your job, Consolas is the font type, 8 is the font's size, and bold is the font type. Other than bold you can go for italic or normal as well.