# Measure the height of a string in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need the height in pixel of a string in a Tkiner widget. It is the text in a row of a `Listbox`.

I know I can measure the width of a string with `tkinter.font.Font.measure`. But how can I get the height?
A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2922295/4865723) thematised only the width but not the height.

Comment: @Nae This only handle the with not the height.

Comment: I don't think that's true. It does claim to show both height _and_ the width.

Comment: @Nae I don't agree. Check the code of the answer. Please give me a line numer or another hint.

Comment: The answer is in the question. :D

Comment: See the 11th line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do the trick.

```
tkinter.font.Font(font='TkDefaultFont').metrics('linespace')
```

Answer (score 9):

```
tkf.Font(font=widget['font']).metrics('linespace')
```

gives the height in pixels of a given widget's font:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.font as tkf
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont as tkf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    widget = tk.Label(root, text="My String")
    widget.pack()
    print(tkf.Font(font=widget['font']).metrics('linespace'))
    tk.mainloop()
```

---

Also note that the height of a one line string isn't dependent on its length, but only on its font in a particular environment.