# Winfo_y does not return correct value

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a custom entry widget in tkinter. When this entry has focus it should display a listbox right under the entry widget with some options to the user. When it loses focus the listbox should delete by itself.

This is what I have:

```
class TestEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.window = top

        tk.Entry.__init__(self, self.window)
        self.listshown = False

        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.showlist)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.hidelist)

    def showlist(self, event):

        if not self.listshown:
            x = self.winfo_x()
            y = self.winfo_y()
            h = self.winfo_height()
            w = self.winfo_width()
    
            # Print bottom left x and y of the entry
            print(x, y, h)

            self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.master, highlightbackground='blue', highlightthickness=1)
            self.listshown = True
            self.listbox.place(x=x, y=y + h, width=w,anchor='nw')
            self.listbox.update()

            # Print top left x,y of listbox
            x = self.listbox.winfo_x()
            y = self.listbox.winfo_y()

            print(x, y)

    def hidelist(self, event):
        if self.listshown:
            self.listbox.destroy()
            self.listshown = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')

    frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Frame')
    frame.pack(padx=30, pady=30, fill='both', expand=True)
    TestEntry(frame).pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=20)
    tk.Entry(frame).pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=20)
```

This is the output that I see:

```
22 218 19
24 254
```

As you can see in the image below, instead of appearing at the left bottom corner of the entry box, listbox appears further below. Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**
This issue only happens when I put my widget in a label frame as shown in the code above. When I put it in a regular frame this does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid all of the math by using relative placement. When you use `place`, you can specify that the listbox is relative to the entry widget.

For example:

```
self.listbox.place(in_=self, relx=0, rely=1.0, bordermode="outside", relwidth=1.0, anchor='nw')
```

- `in_` specifies which widget to be relative to
- `relx` is a floating point value representing the relative x position. 0 == left edge, 1.0 == right edge
- `rely` is a floating point value represeenting the relative y position. A value of 1 means at the bottom of the widget
- `bordermode` means to treat the coordinates relative to the outside border than inside the border
- `relwidth` means to make the widget as wide as the entry widget.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with the label frame. I have now modified my code to check if the master widget is a label frame. If it is a label frame then I subtract the height of the font of the label frame from the y coordinate.

I calculate the height of the font using the answer to this question: ([Measure the height of a string in Tkinter Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726956/measure-the-height-of-a-string-in-tkinter-python))

I also check if it is a frame and then subtract the border width.

Updated code:

```
class TestEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.window = top

        tk.Entry.__init__(self, self.window)
        self.listshown = False

        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.showlist)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.hidelist)

    def showlist(self, event):

        if not self.listshown:
            x = self.winfo_x()
            y = self.winfo_y()
            h = self.winfo_height()
            w = self.winfo_width()

            y = y + h

            # If the master widget is a label frame then substract the height of the frame font from y coordinate
            if 'labelframe' in self.winfo_parent():
                print('master is a label frame')
                height_font = tkf.Font(font=self.master['font']).metrics('linespace')
                y = y - height_font

            # If the master widget is any kind of frame then substract the border width of the frame from x & y
            if 'frame' in self.winfo_parent():
                print('master is a frame')
                width_border = self.master['borderwidth']
                x = x - int(width_border)
                y = y - int(width_border)

            self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.master, highlightbackground='blue', highlightthickness=1)
            self.listshown = True
            self.listbox.place(x=x, y=y, width=w, anchor='nw')
            self.listbox.update()

    def hidelist(self, event):
        if self.listshown:
            self.listbox.destroy()
            self.listshown = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('800x800')

    frame = tk.Frame(root, relief='groove', borderwidth=10)
    frame.pack(padx=30, pady=30, fill='both', expand=True)
    TestEntry(frame).pack(side='top', padx=40)

    label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Label Frame", borderwidth='10', font=('Google Sans', 40, 'bold underline'))
    label_frame.pack(padx=30, pady=30, fill='both', expand=True)
    TestEntry(label_frame).pack(side='top', padx=40)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]